# Trying to combine 2 select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to combine these 2 statements, have tried alot of searches online but I am just flumoxed and tried all sorts of combinations that don't seem to work (in Toad for Oracle).

Help !

statement 1 (to be done once statement 2 done)

```
select * 
from climate_trends.CT05_baseline_values
     inner join climate_trends.CT03_grid_boxes 
       on climate_trends.CT05_baseline_values.location_id 
          = 
          climate_trends.CT03_grid_boxes.grid_box
```

statement 2

```
select * 
from climate_trends.CT05_baseline_values
where averaging_period_id in ('Spr','Sum','Aut','Win')
      and climate_variable_id in('MeanTemp')
      and location_type_id = 'Box'
      and baseline_period = '1981-2010';
```

I've now added the real values if this makes better sense? Trying to get one single table where CT03 holds the spatial reference I need to make the join to...

Comment: Edit your question to include sample data and desired results.

Comment: You want to perform query 1 on result set of query 2?

Comment: There are many different ways to combine two data sets - there are `UNION`s, there are `JOIN`s - we have no idea *what* combination you're trying to form here.

Comment: what is the column linking table 5 and table 3?  It should be as easy as just throwing your inner join table 3 into your second query

Comment: please specify you want union of result or intersect, I mean filter by both condition

Comment: You mean you want to determine the tables you are joining based on the query results?

Comment: The join condition `on table5 = table3` doesn't make sense. A join conditions works on *columns* not *tables*

Comment: Sorry the inner join statement should be: select * from table5.grid_box

Comment: I think Kritner is right. You can just add where clause of second query in first query to get the desired result. Or you need to clear the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [`UNION SELECT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
select * from table5
inner join table3 
on table5 = table3
union
select * from table5
where column1 in ('A','B','C','D')
    and column2 in('Variable1')
    and column3 = 'Variable2'
    and column4 = Variable3';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table3 
join (select * from table5
where column1 in ('A','B','C','D')
    and column2 in('Variable1')
    and column3 = 'Variable2'
    and column4 = Variable3') tabke5 on table5 = table3
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that with `statement 2` you are trying to filter baselines which you got as result of `statement 1`.

If it's right then just add filtering conditions from `statement 2` to `statement 1` :

```
select * 
from climate_trends.CT05_baseline_values as baselines
     inner join climate_trends.CT03_grid_boxes as boxes
       on baselines.location_id = boxes.grid_box
where
  baselines.averaging_period_id in ('Spr','Sum','Aut','Win')
  and 
  baselines.climate_variable_id in('MeanTemp')
  and 
  baselines.location_type_id = 'Box'
  and 
  baselines.baseline_period = '1981-2010'
```